# Disable button and enable it when id is found in database

Tags: html, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm making an application with NodeJs and MySql. I'm taking entries of students in that about the name of the actor which they love most. But I want that only those students can fill that form whose id is already in another table in my database, no new student can enter his/her interest in that table. So I want to disable the submit button and first want to run a query in nodejs where the student id is quals to student id in the existing table...

```
app.post("/register", function(req, res){

 var q= "INSERT INTO students_detail (student_id,actor_name) VALUES ('" + req.body.student_id + "', '" + req.body.actor_name + "' )"
connection.query(q, function(err, result) {
    if (err) res.send("You cant enter Two times");
    else res.redirect("/");
});
```

});

This is the code for posting the data that is provided in the form of the SQL table that I have created.

```
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css">
```

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="container">
    <h1><B>Student Suggesions</h1></B>
    <p class="lead"> Choose Your Actor </p>
    <form method="POST" action='/register'>
        <input type="number" class="form" name="student_id" placeholder="Enter Your ID Number"><br>
        <input type="text" class="form" name="actor_name" placeholder="Name of actor"> <br>
        <button>Vote Now</button>    

</div>
```

This is the HTML for the form.

Comment: Show us some code on what you have tried.

Comment: @Grumpy Sir, Done, Pls check once, I'll be grateful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First create your submit button and make sure it has an id and disable it by default. Modify the existing code `<button>Vote Now</button>` to `<input type="submit" value="Vote Now" id="button1" disabled>`
2. Do this query : `SELECT COUNT(student_id) AS STUDENT_COUNT FROM STUDENTS_CAN_FILL_FORM_TABLE WHERE student_id = <student_id_to_search_for>`. If STUDENT_COUNT > 0 it means the student can submit his or her vote. Enable the disabled button above using this javascript: `document.getElementById("button1").disabled = false;` To disable it again, you can use `document.getElementById("button1").disabled = true;`